# Android: Is it possible to convert a TIFF image to JPG, PNG?

Tags: android, encoding, image, tiff, decoding

I know android does not support TIFF format but I'm getting a Base64 image string from a web service and i need to display it.

```
   byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(serverResponse, Base64.DEFAULT);
   Bitmap imgMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

I tried decoding it with BitmapFactory, but since it doesn't recognize it as a picture it returns null

Is there any external jar or something i can add to display/convert the picture?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to add some C++ to your project via the Android NDK, then [libtiff](http://libtiff.org/) should do what you want.

see question [Convert JPEG/PNG image to TIFF image format in android OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278087/convert-jpeg-png-image-to-tiff-image-format-in-android-os)